# Отсортировать массив на РНР согласно моему порядку

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Есть простой массив на РНР например:

```
$array = array("usd","eur","uah","rub");
```

Нужно отсортировать его согласно моему порядку чтобы получилось:

```
rub uah usd eur
```

Т.е. если брать по ключам то:

```
[3,2,0,1]
```

В Гугле ничего не нашел...

**ОБНОВЛЕНО:** оказывается нужно усложнить задачу. Нужно чтобы первой валютой в списке была та которая установлена в переменной, например:

```
$defaultCurrency = 'eur';
```

Соответственно ее нужно поставить первой, а остальные после нее в порядке:

```
eur rub uah usd
```

Валютой по умолчанию может быть любая

Comment: 1) можно преобразовать к виду `[key => value]` и тогда сортировка не важна, т.к. выбирать можете как захотите 2) либо использовать [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php), т.е. разбиваете через implode по | и сравниваете ключи как вам надо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно отсортировать неассоциативный массив в порядке, заданном в другом массиве, можно сделать ассоциативный массив из значений первого и ключей из значений второго, отсортировать по ключам и вытащить массив значений из результата.

Только в массиве, который задает порядок должны идти номера, которые вы хотели бы присвоить соответствующим элементам исходного массива. То есть если хотите первым видеть `"rub"` в "порядковом массиве" должно быть наменьшее число.

```
$array = array("usd", "eur", "uah", "rub");
$orderArray = array(2, 3, 1, 0);

$tmpArray = array_combine($orderArray, $array);
ksort($tmpArray, SORT_NUMERIC);
$array = array_values($tmpArray);
```

**Добавлено**

По поводу доп. вопроса вот вам два решения:
В любом случае нужно найти номер элемента со значением `$defaultCurrency`.

```
$defaultIndex = array_search($defaultCurrency, $array);
```

Дальше первый вариант:

```
if ($defaultIndex !== FALSE) {
    $orderArray[$defaultIndex] = -1; /* Это чтобы указать
        что соответствующий элемент должен быть самым первым */
}
// Тут предложенная выше сортировка
```

Второй вариант:

```
if ($defaultIndex !== FALSE) {
    unset($array[$defaultIndex]);
    unset($orderArray[$defaultIndex]);
}
// Тут сортировка
if ($defaultIndex !== FALSE) {
    array_unshift($array, $defaultCurrency); /* Заталкиваем
        значение по-умолчанию в начало массива */
}
```

Comment: @stckvrw Обновил ответ

Answer (score 2):

Для начала, это не массив, а какая-то ерунда. Массив - это

```
$array = [
    "euro" => 2700,
    "uah"  => 2400,
    "usd"  => 100,
    "rub"  => 6600,
];
```

А отсортировать такой простой массив будет проще всего вручную

```
$array = [
    "rub"  => $array['rub']
    "euro" => $array['euro'],
    "uah"  => $array['uah'],
    "usd"  => $array['usd'],
];
```

Comment: А что в результате последних пяти строк изменилось?

Comment: Оставьте, это я вопрос обновил свой

Comment: @stckvrw Я к тому, что ничего же не поменялось. Может быть автор ответа имел ввиду что-то другое, но ошибся при написании ответа

Comment: Нет, не ошибся, просто в начале у меня были еще числа рядом с названием каждой валюты и он подумал что названия валют это должны быть ключи массива, в общем не важно, забудьте

Comment: Хотя почему не поменялось: в первом ведь массиве порядок другой, там где валюты с цифрами

Comment: @stckvrw Логично. Вопрос снят

Answer (score 0):

В общем, вот так должно быть:

```
$array = array("usd","euro","uah","rub");
$sortedArray = array($array[3], $array[2], $array[0], $array[1]);
```

Comment: И вы это считаете ответом? А зачем вы переделываете простой массив в ассоциативный? Если у вас массив маленький, то достаточно сделать так: `$sortedArray = array($array[3], $array[2], $array[0], $array[1]);`

Comment: Точно, спасибо! Исправил

Answer (score 0):

В чистом виде [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-multisort.php):

```
$orderArray = array(3, 0, 2, 1);
$array = array("usd", "eur", "uah", "rub");

var_dump($orderArray);
var_dump($array);

array_multisort($orderArray, $array);

var_dump($orderArray);
var_dump($array);
```

Работает так:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => int 3
  1 => int 0
  2 => int 2
  3 => int 1
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'usd' (length=3)
  1 => string 'eur' (length=3)
  2 => string 'uah' (length=3)
  3 => string 'rub' (length=3)
array (size=4)
  0 => int 0
  1 => int 1
  2 => int 2
  3 => int 3
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'eur' (length=3)
  1 => string 'rub' (length=3)
  2 => string 'uah' (length=3)
  3 => string 'usd' (length=3)
```